# How frequently do PaaS:VPS agencies upgrade OS_release in comparison to PaaS:shared-webserver?

Tags: linux, vagrant, release-management, platform-as-a-service

I know that in a In *PaaS:shared-webserver* service a user could have the OS of its server environment **release_upgraded** in 8 or 12 years or so ! For example, I host a few sites on a particular host that uses a very old version of CentOS (from about 2007).

I never used a *PaaS:VPS* service (like AWS/MSA/GCP) and I wonder if they have a different standard of doing OS release_upgrades; for example, I wonder if due to utilization of OS deployment tools like Vagrant, it might it be say per each new release (say, each 2 years) instead?

How frequently do PaaS:VPS agencies upgrade OS_release in comparison to PaaS:shared-webserver?

Comment: In a VPS *you* are responsible of the OS updates.

Comment: AFAIK, when it is PaaS, the client doesn't control it; for example, I host a few siites on a PaaS:shared-webserver (SiteGround) and I don't control the OS --- it might be release_upgraded without me knowing this. Are you sure it's not the case for neither PaaS;VPS like AWS/MSA/GCP?...

Comment: A vps by definition gives you an OS with full control. As does a IaaS, as soon as yo  have admin account on the machine you have to handle the updates. Some providers gives helpers but it's still your task to configure that

Comment: But were does the line line between these helpers to the OS-itself configuration gets drawn? In a PaaS;VPS of SiteGround (they also have a VPS for 60$) they told me everything stays the same; you still have SSH, cronjobs from Cpanel, daily backups and applications but AFAIK no root and no controlling of the OS... Some small answer from your experience with other PaaS;VPSs you have tried could be very helpful to understand were that line is usually drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience this is very provider specific and requires evaluating the [SLA](http://Service-level%20agreement) offered for a particular service.

For example the **siteground** cloud server offerings shown at
https://www.siteground.com/cloud-hosting.htm state: *We preinstall and maintain all the software you need on your server.*

While offerings from **liquidweb** they make it clear they will customize the support level to fit your requirements (the custom levels of management are [detailed here](https://www.liquidweb.com/support/compare/)). You can chose the support level for the product you purchase, whether it's a cloud VPS or dedicated server hardware.

IMHO most cloud products will probably be vendor managed and provide you a way to perform needed customization. But general statements are not useful when it comes to spending money. You have to confirm what your vendor is providing.

Comment: I just got an email from Azure Webapps telling me `App Service helps you save the time and effort of managing servers, patching operating systems, and dealing with security concerns—so you can focus on your code and aligning the scale to your needs`.